# Conflict between suckerfish menu and adgallery

Tags: jquery, css, suckerfish

A site I'm working on uses JQuery's ADGallery and Superfish menus. The problem I'm having is to do with the way layers stack.

The page http://severnsystems-sms.co.uk/pd_about_us.htm demonstrates the problem. Hovering over the "Profile" menu shows the slide numbers and also the "next" arrow on top of the menu.

I have set the z-index for the menu items higher than the other items thoguh so I do not understand why it should display in the way it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative; z-index: 120` to your parent `ul` - `.sf-menu`. It will help ;)

Comment: One thousand "I love you"'s. But why?

Comment: I was really surprised at this case myself ;) Imo, it should have worked the way you tried